# Jquery getting a url id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get an id from a url string generated in php depending on the page you are viewing the id can appear in different places for example

```
site.com/view.php?id=12&person=23
```

or

```
site.com/view.php?loc=man&id=1782&person=43
```

I just need to get the id section using JQuery any ideas

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` to get the `id` from URL.

```
var id = url.match(/id=(\d+)/)[1]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/v0tmevLz/)

**REGEX Explanation**

1. `/`: Delimiters of `regex`
2. `id=`: Matches literal `id=`
3. `()` : Capturing group
4. `\d+`: Matches one or more numbers